# Determain a Sprites Movement Speed.....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a Sprite and his walk speed is set too move 1 pixel every 100 milliseconds.

Const Walk_Speed = 100 ' Milliseconds

If i want the Sprite to move slower, I increase his walk speed in milliseconds. If i change the Sprites speed to 200 Milliseconds, he then moves 1 pixel every 200 milliseconds. Setting it to 50 milliseconds moves the Sprite Faster of course.

What I am trying to figure out is this.....

On my map, where the sprite will move around on. Different Terrains will have different speed modifiers, the values being from .1 to 2.5 or more...

> Moving on a Plain would be normal speed, 1.0
>
> Hills would be speed, .8
>
> Mountains would be speed, .5
>
> Moving on a road would be speed, 1.2

What math equation can I setup to obtain the correct Millisecond Value?

IE....

100 millisecond speed, with a .5 modifier should reduce the Sprites speed by half, making his new millisecond speed to be 200.

And if there is a 1.5 Speed modifier then the sprite should move at a faster speed.

I hope i explained this right, Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the variable that you are setting is the amount of time required for the sprite to move 1 pixel (e.g. 100 milliseconds to move 1 pixel) not speed. This is confusing, so let me explain a better way.

In general, speed is defined as distance per time, so your speed should be pixels per second (or pixels per millisecond if you want). So, if you default speed is 1 pixels per 100 milliseconds, you should define your default speed as

$$\textsf{speed} = \frac{\textsf{distance}}{\textsf{time}} = \frac{1 \; \textsf{pixel}}{100 \; \textsf{millisecconds}}$$

Now, you can simply change your speed by multiplying your speed by some constant say $c$. So, if you need to know the time required to travel a single pixel, you can just do some basic algebra to get your time by rearranging and multiplying speed by $c$.

$$\textsf{time} = \frac{1}{c \times\textsf{speed}}$$

Comment: Awesome That works Perfectly and was just what i needed. Thank you Very Much!

Comment: Great! No problem.